# Unusual CPU temperature spikes

Tags: cpu, fan, temperature

First, I know (kind of) that a CPU temperature of more than about 60<sup>**o**</sup>**C** for long periods is not good. In Core Temp, I see the max CPU temperature reported as high as above 80<sup>**o**</sup>**C**, for no apparent reason. I have not been playing games, or editing ultra HD videos (actually not even running such videos for that matter). Most of the time CPU fans are quiet, and live temperature readings are also well within acceptable ranges. But, while playing games the live temperature readings go as high as about 70<sup>**o**</sup>**C** or a little more. I am more concerned about the max CPU temperature readings shown by Core Temp, as I am not sure if this is something I should be concerned at all. Following is a screenshot of Core Temp (note the max temperature** readings only, which is the main focus of this post).

[image: CoreTemp screenshot]

My laptop configuration:

- Model: [ASUS S15 S510UN](https://www.asus.com/bd/Laptops/ASUS-VivoBook-S15-S510UN/specifications/)
- CPU: Core i5 8250U
- GPU: 1) NVIDIA® GeForce® MX150, with 2GB GDDR5 VRAM, 2) Integrated Intel UHD Graphics 620
- RAM 8GB

My typical use case consists of 1 or a few Visual Studio instances, chrome with never more than about 10-12 tabs (point is, nothing so heavy that this newly bought laptop can't handle).

**Question:** Is this CPU temperature reading something to be worried about, considering the spikes as high as 85<sup>**o**</sup>**C**?

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with the specific tool you are using.

However, my reading of that display is that it is displaying:

- The current temperature reading (well within range)
- The lowest temperature reading recorded this session ("Min")
- The maximum temperature reading recorded this session ("Max")

There is no information in that display regarding how long the specific core spent at that temperature.  It could have been at that temperature for one second 3 days ago (if you leave your computer on, or if the tool keeps history across reboots).  You point out in your question: "I know (kind of) that a CPU temperature of more than about 60oC **for long periods** is not good" [emphasis added].

It seems reasonable to me to assume that your computer is operating correctly, that the CPU temperature hit 84oC briefly and was cooled by the fan at that time back down to normal operating temperatures.  You can more closely monitor the temperatures using the tool you show a screenshot of if you are concerned, but if your computer is operating correctly, I would not jump to the conclusion that the 84oC reading is a sign of a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My concern is more due to that number beside _Tj. Max_ which is 100, and the fact that max temp my CPU reached is awfully close to that number, which is what worries me most.

Comment: Tj max is the [junction temp max](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_temperature) figure, which you got nowhere near. If you're running the machine hard, then you can actually sit 1° below Tj Max all day. That's what the CPU temperature-safety rating is for.

Comment: You were 16 degrees away from the maximum junction temperature, you didn’t even get close to that temperature.  Unless you have an actual symptom, that provides evidence your laptop is overheating, your temperatures are fine.

Comment: @Ramhound Phew! Thanks very much. Boy was I worried! I believe ya alright, but can you give me a reference or something that explains why/how my temperatures are fine? Maybe you can add an answer of your own with those details, and I will be more than happy to mark that as accepted. ;)